# ¿Cómo saber cuando una página ha terminado de cargar en un WebBrowser?

Tags: c#, windows-forms

Estoy navegando páginas en VisualStudio 2012 con C#, el problema es que no puedo saber cuando la página terminó de cargar completamente, el `WebBrowser` tiene un evento llamado `DocumentCompleted` pero pasa varias veces por ese evento antes de terminar de terminar de cargar la página.

¿Hay alguna manera de saber cuando la página esta cargada por completo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Quizá el evento DocumentCompleted corresponda a otro tipo de proceso en la navegación.*

Para saber cuando ha terminado de transferir datos en la web, necesitas el evento Navigated. El otro evento que necesitarás para determinar cuando hay cambios al respecto es Navigating, con el sabrás cuando el control WebBrowser está transfiriendo datos en la web. Luego con Navigated controlas cuando ha terminado de cargar.

Te sugiero que actives sendos eventos, Navigating y Navigated, en el objeto WebBrowser de tu aplicación, y que programes y compruebes los cambios de estado de navegación ( Loading / Loaded ) en el texto de una Label.

*He comprobado que estos eventos hacen lo que pides en el IDE.*

Como viene en este código ..

```
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace pruebaWebBrowser
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void webBrowser1_Navigating(object sender, WebBrowserNavigatingEventArgs e)
        {
            Estado.Text = "Loading";
        }

        private void webBrowser1_Navigated(object sender, WebBrowserNavigatedEventArgs e)
        {
            Estado.Text = "Loaded";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, me sirvio bastante

Comment: Me alegro. Siendo así, puedes indicarla como : Respuesta que más me ha ayudado.